# Almost missed the left navigation options

Tags: support, bug, design, left-nav

Almost missed the navigation links on the left. Have to make them more clear.

OS is :- Linux Debojyoti 4.4.0-119-generic #143~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 2 18:04:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Browser is :- Google chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Note:- Please ignore the multiple robot images in the screenshot. They are shown due to the tool which was used for screenshot.Just the text colors somewhat gets mixed with the image of the robot.

[image]

Comment: What browser/system? The robot should not be tiling like that.

Comment: @Catija: Could it have something to do with the giant "not-logged-in" bar of the user on that page?

Comment: @Catija I think this is caused by the tool used to create the screenshot?

Comment: @Catija  os is :- Linux Debojyoti 4.4.0-119-generic #143~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 2 18:04:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @Catija browser is :- Google chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @NicolBolas Have given the os and browser versions.